# ActionListener: данные из двух класов

Tags: java, swing

Новичок в SWING просит помощи

Есть два WindowsPanel. В разных классах, кнопки отдельно, поля для ввода отдельно.

```
public class WindowFrame extends JFrame {

    WindowFrame(){
        WindowPanel windowPanel = new WindowPanel();
        WindowPanel2 windowPanel2 = new WindowPanel2();
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (400,600));
            this.add(windowPanel);
            this.add(windowPanel2);
            this.setFocusable(true);
            this.pack();
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setTitle("Calculator");
            }

    }

public class WindowPanel extends JPanel {

    TextField textField1;
    TextField textField2;
    TextField textField3;

    WindowPanel(){
        this.setLayout(null);
        Label label1 = new Label();
        this.add(label1);
        label1.setText("First digit");
        label1.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 20);
        TextField textField1 = new TextField();
        textField1.setBounds(50, 70, 200, 30);
        this.add(textField1);
}


public class WindowPanel2 extends JPanel {

    WindowPanel2(){
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        ButtonListener1 bl1 = new ButtonListener1(this);
        Button button1 = new Button("+");
        this.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                float first = Float.parseFloat(WindowPanel.textField1.getText());
                float second = Float.parseFloat(WindowPanel.textField2.getText());
                float result = first + second;
                WindowPanel.textField1.setText("");
                WindowPanel.textField2.setText("");
                WindowPanel.textField3.setText(Float.toString(result));
            }
        });
}
```

При запуске выдает ошибку NPE, то есть не получает значение поля "textField".

В чем я не прав?

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, я не понимаю, как этот код вообще скомпилировался, так как Вы пытаетесь обратиться к нестатическим полям класса `WindowPanel` через имя класса:

```
float first = Float.parseFloat(WindowPanel.textField1.getText());
```

Ошибка как минимум в том, что при обращении к элементам интерфейса Вы пытаетесь обратиться к полям класса `WindowPanel`, а не к полям созданного Вами объекта `windowPanel` класса `WindowPanel`.

**UPD**. И как <s>подсказывают</s> подсказывали в комментарии, в конструкторе `WindowPanel()` Вы не инициализируете поля класса: локальная переменная конструктора `TextField textField1` скрывает одноименное поле класса, а остальные два поля Вы вообще не инициализируете.